# how to create a big list of divs in small div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create some thing like a small feed in a small box(div)in the corner of my website, How can i do it ?
how can i do this small box that can fit a lot of divs and make it scrollable?

Comment: You can use `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.feed{
height:30%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>
<div class="feed">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how could i make it scrollable without the scroll bar shown ?? because that make it more ui friendly

Comment: You must put your feed element into a div element with hidden scroll (overflow: hidden)

Answer (score 1):

The point is using `overflow: scroll` for big div style. It does scroll horizontally and verticaly. If you want to just scroll horizontally, use `overflow-y:scroll`. And if you want to just scroll verticaly , use `overflow-y:scroll`. So try this:

```css
.big-div{
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-div">
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
  <div>List item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you i appreciate it, that helps me.

Comment: i'll do it after 4 min , that's what it says

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: scroll`. You might want to hide the scrollbar as well, you can do it as follow:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.scroll-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll-container">
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
    <div> feed </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how could i make it scrollable without the scroll bar shown ?? because that make it more ui friendly